# Error: Attempt to call private method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, access-specifier, private-methods

Coming from a long history of C-style syntax and now trying to learn Ruby (on Rails), I've been having my share of issues with its idioms and such, but today I hit one I didn't expect to have a problem with and I can't see whatever it is that must be right in front of my face.

I have a Binary class that includes a private method to derive a URI value from a path value (uri and path are attributes of the class). I'm calling `self.get_uri_from_path()` from within `Binary.upload()`, but I get:

```
Attempt to call private method
```

A snippet of the model looks like this:

```
class Binary < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :image

  def upload( uploaded_file, save = false )
    save_as = File.join( self.get_bin_root(), '_tmp', uploaded_file.original_path )

    # write the file to a temporary directory
    # set a few object properties

    self.path   = save_as.sub( Rails.root.to_s + '/', '' )
    self.uri    = self.get_uri_from_path()
  end

  private

  def get_uri_from_path
    return self.path.sub( 'public', '' )
  end
end
```

Am I making the call incorrectly? Am I missing something else that's even more fundamental? The only place that `Binary.get_uri_from_path()` is being called from - at the moment - is `Binary.upload()`. I'd expect to be able to call a private method from within the same class unless Ruby does something markedly different from other languages I've used.

Thanks.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Don't do

```
self.get_uri_from_path()
```

do

```
get_uri_from_path()
```

Because...

```
  class AccessPrivate
    def a
    end
    private :a # a is private method

    def accessing_private
      a              # sure! 
      self.a         # nope! private methods cannot be called with an explicit receiver at all, even if that receiver is "self"
      other_object.a # nope, a is private, you can't get it (but if it was protected, you could!)
    end
  end
```

[via](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Classes)

Comment: Thanks. A little more digging helped me understand the differences in private methods of Ruby vs. other languages. I just didn't expect differences at that level.

Comment: you're welcome. It's true it's a bit more tricky, but it actually makes sense after a while :)

Comment: I'm finding that a lot of Ruby is terrific - laconic, yet expressive - but I'm definitely having to fight through the idiom deltas. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the proper idiom in this case is not self.get_uri_from_path() but rather simply get_uri_from_path(). The self is redundant. Further notes:
* self.path calls the path method on self, which is presumably defined in the parent class. If you had wanted to access the instance variable directly, you could have said @path. (@ is the sigil for instance variables.)
* Parentheses for method arguments are optional except where their absence would cause ambiguity. You could, if you chose, replace get_uri_from_path() with get_uri_from_path. This stands in contrast to Javascript, where a function with no parens represents that function as a value rather than an application of that function.

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware of the optional parens, but I keep seeing stuff without them and I don't like the ambiguity. Is it a variable or is it a method? I'd rather not have to ask myself that question every time I see it. Maybe that gets easier over time.

Answer (score 1):

there is a heck though where you can call private method in any situation, that being:

```
object.send(:private_method)
```

I believe 1.9 has a different implementation of this trick

Comment: Yes, 1.9 has the send! method.

Comment: At this point, I'm just trying to learn and understand the rules. I'll worry about "breaking" them later. :-)

Comment: 1.9.2 does not have the `send!` method. It does have `send` though.